# SQL Server : extract string after multiple line feeds until line feed after string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have text in a field that has multiple line feeds and possibly carriage returns, after which there is string then more line feeds and carriage returns. I want to extract text after the line feed / carriage return up till the next line feed. So from the example below I would want to extract the line Some text. numbers are to highlight carriage return/line feed not actual field data.

Example (with line numbers for demonstration only):

```
1
2
3
4
5 Some text
6
7 Some more text
8
9 Even more text
```

Expected output (the first line that is not empty):

```
Some text
```

Comment: So what exactly do you want the output to be?

Comment: The 1st line of text only which in above example is "Some text"

Answer (score 2):

Sounds to me like you simply need to split this string on carriage returns. The challenge however is that most splitters (even the Microsoft one) does not return the element number. Fortunately Jeff Moden has a splitter that does which makes it an excellent choice for this type of thing. It has some other limitations but works great here. You can read about the splitter [here](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/). Make sure to read the comments as well as there is a lengthy discussion in there.

Using the DelimitedSplit8K that you will find in that article this is pretty straight forward.

```
declare @Something table(SomeVal varchar(500))

insert @Something
select char(13) + char(13) + char(13) + 'Some text' + char(13) + 'more text'

select top 1 x.Item
from @Something s
cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.SomeVal, char(13))x
where x.Item > ''
order by x.ItemNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the response I ended up writing the below code and at does what I require, so didn't end up using the DelimitedSplit8K but it might be useful in the future.

,case charindex(char(10), [Field])
     when 0 then [Field]
     else
     SUBSTRING ( [Field] ,PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field]) , 
    case PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field]) - charindex(char(10), [Field],PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field])) -(PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field]))
       when 0 then (LEN([Field])- charindex(char(10), [Field],PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field])) ) 
       else
       charindex(char(10), [Field],PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field])) -(PATINDEX('%[^'+CHAR(10)+']%',[Field]))
       end
        )
    end as [Field]